# proof of $\lim_{k\to\infty} x_{n_k} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup x_n $

Tags: real-analysis, sequences-and-series

proof of $\lim_{k\to\infty} x_{n_k} = \lim_{n\to\infty} \sup x_n $

[image]

$a_{n_{k-1}+1} = \sup\{a_{n_{k-1}+1},a_{n_{k-1}+2},a_{n_{k-1}+3},a_{n_{k-1}+4},....\}$, or $a_{n_{k-1}+1} = \sup\{a_{n_{k-1}+1},a_{n_{k}+1},a_{n_{k+1}+1},a_{n_{k+2}+1},....\}$ Could you tell me which one is right?, and  I also don't understand why $a_{n_{k-1}+1}\ge a_{n_k}$.
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The former equlaity is right. You just have to put $n_{k-1}+1$ in place of $n$ in the definition of $a_n$.
Also, since $n_{k-1}+1 \leq n_k$, the set where the supremum is taken is larger for $n_{k-1}+1$. That is,$$\{l\geq n_k\} \subset \{l\geq n_{k-1}+1\}$$

Comment: How do you know that $n_{k-1}+1 \le n_k$ ??

Comment: @sihyunkim that is the way you construct a subsequence

Comment: I am confused because I know that $n_{k-1} < n_k$, but how are we sure about $n_{k-1}+1 \le n_k$ ??

Comment: @sihyunkim well because they are integers